# What are the benefits of encapsulating conditionals (in functions)?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

According to this clean-code guide you should encapsulate conditionals:

```
function shouldShowSpinner() {
  return fsm.state === 'fetching' && isEmpty(listNode);
}

if (shouldShowSpinner()) {
  // ...
}
```

Why not just write:

```
const shouldShowSpinner = fsm.state === 'fetching' && isEmpty(listNode)

if (shouldShowSpinner) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because

```
const shouldShowSpinner = fsm.state === 'fetching' && isEmpty(listNode)
```

is only evaluated once.  The assignment operator `=` stores the result of a single evaluation of the boolean expression.

This is fine if the state of the boolean expression never changes during code execution in the relevant scope, but will produce wrong results if it does change, in which case you will get the now inaccurate result of the original calculation.

Comment: +1 but would also add that `if (shouldShowSpinner()){` is alot more readable than `if (fsm.state === 'fetching' && isEmpty(listNode)) {`.

Comment: @Maybe_Factor: `if (shouldShowSpinner)` would also be easy to read, if it actually worked.

Comment: And the corollary to this is, if you want to correctly check `if (shouldShowSpinner)` later on, you wind up rewriting this code each time you need to check it. That's the perfect candidate for encapsulation.

Comment: Additionally, shouldShowSpinner() is more testable, especially if the criteria for showing spinners changes.